# Как сделать submit по клику на компонент?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, submit, formik

суть вопроса в том что AddBoxSharpIcon это компонент icons-material, я пробовал доставать форму через getElementsById и в onClick писать form(переменная полученная через getElementsById).submit() , но получал ошибку Cannot read properties of null (reading 'submit'), как мне добиться сабмита формы?

```
<Formik initialValues={{ body: "" }} onSubmit={addTask}>
  <Form className={styles.formContainer} id="form-id">
    <Field name="body" />
    <div className={styles.addCross}>
      <AddBoxSharpIcon onclick={submit()} fontSiza="small" />  // Должен происходить сабмит 
    </div>
  </Form>
</Formik>
```